# GreenRobot eventbus gradle upgrade failed with de.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1

Tags: android, event-bus, greenrobot-eventbus-3.0

When I tried to upgrade the eventbus SDK with dependancy `"de.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1"`, it says couldn't resolve `"de.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer, we need to use the dependancy `org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1` instead of `de.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1`.

For more info : https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: I am getting unable to compile classpath when I tried to build